# Python - Error making migrations

Tags: python, django, migration, database-migration

Im having trouble making some migrations to my Django Project.

Here's the code.

```css
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class MovieSceneType(md.Model):      
 """docstring for Movie_Scene_Type"""      
 name = md.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)      
 id = md.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Movie(md.Model): 
 """docstring for Movie""" 
 movie_type = md.ForeignKey(MovieSceneType, verbose_name="the related Movie Type") 
 id = md.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Actor(md.Model):      
 """docstring for Actor"""      
 name = md.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)      
 id = md.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Scene(md.Model):      
 """docstring for Scene"""      
 location = md.CharField(max_length=100)      
 actor = md.ForeignKey(Actor, verbose_name="the related main actor", blank=True)     
 movie_scene_type = md.ForeignKey(MovieSceneType, verbose_name="his type")      
 start_time = md.DateTimeField()      
 end_time = md.DateTimeField()

class Team(md.Model):      
 """docstring for Team"""      
 name = md.CharField(max_length=100)      
 country = md.CharField(max_length=100)

class Game(md.Model):      
 """docstring for Game"""      
 HOMEAWAY = [("H", "HOME"), ("A", "AWAY")]      
 start_datetime = md.DateTimeField()      
 location = md.CharField(max_length=100, choices=HOMEAWAY)      
 team_home = md.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="team_home", verbose_name="the related team_home")      
 team_away = md.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="team_away", verbose_name="the related team_away")

class Assessment(md.Model):      
 """docstring for Assessment"""      
 scene = md.ForeignKey(Scene, related_name="scene", verbose_name="the related scene")
```

I do the command - python manage.py makemigrations and end up with this error.

File "C:\trickatcher\movies\models.py", line 5, in 
    class MovieSceneType(md.Model):
NameError: name 'md' is not defined

Any idea why this happens? Im following a tutorial from my teacher so this should not happen.

Comment: Because it's not `md`, it's `models`, as your `from django.db import models` says.

Comment: @spectras So I just replace md with models and it should work?

Comment: Why don't you try it? It would have been faster that writing your comment, and you'd have the answer without having to wait for me to reply ^^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The variable md is not defined anywhere in your models, it must be models not md, if you want to with md you can change your import

```
from django.db import models
```

to

`from django.db import models as md`

Comment: It is not a good idea. Django devs are used to having the module called `models`. Changing its name will hurt readability for no reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked and the migrations were done.

Comment: @Dany4k> it is still a bad idea. You should replace `md` with `models` in your code instead.

Comment: @spectras I don't think it is bad idea as django itself uses like this 
for Ex: from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
The above code pasted will be in django repo only.

Comment: @Chaitanyak> yes, it is usual to use `_` as the name of the internationalization function, the very same way it is usual to use `models` as the name of the module here. Changing them for no reason is a bad idea.